# Accelerating python processing.. [Google Colab]

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a python program which I want to accelerate using GPU on Google colaboratory.

The program have basic for looping, reading and writing to file operations.
I ran the file on google colab. and found no change in execution time.

How could I accelerate python's for loops, reading and writing to files? Can I accelerate these operations on a GPU?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed no, you can't. GPU runtime in google colaboratory is provided to accelerate deep learning operations such as matrix multiplications. Basic python operations  cannot be accelerated. But anyway, your code can be executed under CPU backend. Maybe google colab cpu can do it faster than your own cpu.